# Inserting with loop in trigger in sql

Tags: sql, while-loop, triggers, sql-insert, sap-ase

I have to have an after insert update trigger, which has to populate another table with the information got from inserted/updated row and sequential numbers from 1 to 99.

The final table should look like something like this.

```
Column 1      Column 2
Info 1        1
Info 1        2
...
Info 1        98
Info 1        99
Info 2        1
...
```

But I can't figure out how the trigger should work.
It shoud be something like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER tg_treeningrupi_numbrid AFTER
INSERT, UPDATE ON treeninggrupid
REFERENCING NEW AS uus
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a INTEGER = 1; 
    WHILE @a < 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Numbrid_treeninggrupis
        (treeninggrupp, number)
        VALUES
        (uus.id, @a);
        SET @a = @a + 1;
    END;
END;
```

Please don't mind the names ;)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Sybase